# Add value to existing graphene.Enum

Tags: python, enums, graphene-python, graphene-sqlalchemy

Is there a way to add a value to an existing `graphene.Enum`?

I want to use graphene-sqlalchemy [sort_enum()](https://github.com/graphql-python/graphene-sqlalchemy/blob/20ecaeadf2144b88555a3daf1a04e31b7f2ff95a/graphene_sqlalchemy/enums.py#L162) functionality and to add additional functionality of my own - `TOTAL_COUNT_ASC` and `TOTAL_COUNT_DESC` that will enable sorting by total count, but I can figure out how to do it. Directly adding the fields to the graphene.Enum doesn't work:

```
SqlModel.sort_enum().TOTAL_COUNT_ASC = "TOTAL_COUNT_ASC"
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way that I found is:

```py
from graphene_sqlalchemy import utils

# Take the original Enum
ExtendedValues  = [(m.name, m.value) for m in SqlModel.sort_enum()._meta.enum]
# Add the new values with EnumValue
ExtendedValues += [("TOTAL_COUNT_ASC", utils.EnumValue('TOTAL_COUNT_ASC', sqlalchemy.func.count())), ('TOTAL_COUNT_DESC', utils.EnumValue('TOTAL_COUNT_DESC', sqlalchemy.func.count().desc()))]
# Create the extended graphene enum
ExtendedEnum = graphene.Enum("ExtendedEnum", ExtendedValues)
```